# One to One Relationshipe: How to automatically create the dependency object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i'm beginner in JPA/Hibernate. I have 2 classes that must to be linked in One to One relationship. I have this class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table (name = "doc")
    public class Document {

        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "doc_cd_doc_seq")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "doc_cd_doc_seq", sequenceName = "doc_cd_doc_seq")
        @Column(name = "cd_doc")
        private Long code;

 }
```

and when I construct this I wanna create his dependency (another object, another table), with sequence generator:

```
    @Entity
    @Table (name= "attached_doc_info")
    public class AttachedDocInfo {
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "attached_doc_info_cd_attached_doc_info_seq")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "attached_doc_info_cd_attached_doc_info_seq", sequenceName = "attached_doc_info_cd_attached_doc_info_seq")
        @Column(name = "acd_attached_doc_info)
        private Long code;

        @JoinColumn(name = "cd_doc", referencedColumnName = "cd_doc")
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Document document;

    ...
    }
```

My problem is that when I create a Document, the AttachedDocInfo object is not being automatically created in his table (attached_doc_info table). Can you guys tell me where I went wrong? TY!

Comment: You miss the reference from  `DocInfo` to `AttachedDocInfo`

Comment: In your model, a Doc is an independent entity - it can exist without a AttachedDocInfo and has no knowledge of one.  You should try creating a AttachedDocInfo instance, associate it to a Document and persist both - JPA will not do it for you.